# how to make multiple input validation using HTML5?

Tags: html, validation

HTML5 provides alternate of JavaScript validation using Regular Expression.
But I want to add multiple validation on single input field and according to that it should show the message.

For example.

`<input type=passowrd name=passowrd/>`

Here password field should contains following validation with message.
[image]

Comment: Yeah, that's too complex for HTML alone. You need JavaScript to go along with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid it cannot be done with HTML alone (no, not even HTML5).

You'll have to use JavaScript to achieve the task.

Answer (score 1):

Constraint validation is only designed for one error message per input field. A way to get around this is to concatenate the validation messages.

```
password.setCustomValidity(password.validationMessage + ' At least one capital letter');
```

The downside is that you can't append html, so all messages will be placed inline.