# Validate all fields at once with HTML5 instead of one at a time

Tags: css, html, validation

Is there a way to make HTML5 validate all fields at once instead of one at a time?

Using a couple of lines of JavaScript is OK but I don't really want to use an entire module for this.

I've searched quite a bit but couldn't find a clean solution for this.

Here is a sample form:

```html
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Validation Test</title>
      <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
   </head>
   <body>
      <form action="" id="myForm" method="post">
         <input id="name" name="name" required type="text">
         <input id="phone" name="phone" required type="text">
         <input type="submit" value="Submit">
      </form>
   </body>
</html>
```

**Css file:**

```css
input:focus:required:invalid {
   border: 2px solid red !important;
}
```

*The post suggested as a possible duplicate is for having multiple validation conditions for one field, I'm looking to validate / show all invalid fields at once.*

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to make multiple input validation using HTML5?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14114267/how-to-make-multiple-input-validation-using-html5)

Comment: Thanks, but that post is for having multiple validation conditions for one field, I'm looking to validate / show all invalid fields at once.

Comment: Are you just doing basic (no null fields) validation, or something more complex?

Comment: Do you want the browser's default validation error messages to show for all invalid elements at once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to use jQuery, that is fine. You can easily do this with vanilla js event handlers, and DOM selectors. I'm using jQuery for the sake of saving me time.

```
$('#myForm').on('submit', function() {
  var $inputs = $(this).find(':input'),
      isValid = true;

  $inputs.each(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == '') {
      isValid = false;
      $(this).addClass('error-control');
    } else {
      $(this).removeClass('error-control');
    }
  });

  return isValid  
});
```

Comment: This actually worked nicely with what I was doing, thanks.

Comment: Quite new to JS, where in the code do you put "vanilla js event handlers" inside script tag?

Answer (score -1):

Use the onSubmit on the Form tag:

See: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_validation.asp

```
  <form action="" id="myForm" method="post" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
```

Js:

```
function validateForm() {
    // validate form here
    // return false if there are errors
    // return true to submit the form
}
```

Comment: submit event doesn't trigger until all fields are validated.